# Console. Minha aplicação funciona normalmente mais não consigo usar o Console

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2

Minha aplicação funciona normalmente mais quando eu tento usar o Console ela da o seguinte erro:

> PHP Warning:  include(Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php): failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/devidy/www/es/Console/cake.php on line 23 PHP Warning: 
>   include(): Failed opening 'Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php' for
>   inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in
>   /home/devidy/www/es/Console/cake.php on line 23 PHP Fatal error: 
>   Could not locate CakePHP core files. in
>   /home/devidy/www/es/Console/cake.php on line 24
>   devidy@nurturing-02:~/www/es$

Olhei na internet mais não achei muita coisa. Alguém aí já viu algo parecido?

Comment: Pergunta básica, você desenvolve no Windows e seu ambiente de produção é linux? Caso sim, já conferiu se os nomes das pastas estão em *case sensitive*?

Comment: além do que o @ErlonCharles disse, você ja verificou se o arquivo existe?

Comment: @ErlonCharles Eu desenvolvo no no Ubuntu 14.04. O arquivo existe sim.

Comment: @DevidyOliviera como você está chamando a aplicação via shell?

Comment: @ErlonCharles -Sim. "sudo INSTANCE=ipa Console/cake Sms smsReport 66403836D"

Answer (score 0):

Você provavelmente está usando o Cake instalado em outro diretório do que sua aplicação.

No arquivo `/Console/cake.php` altere a linha:

```
ini_set('include_path', $root . $ds . 'lib' . PATH_SEPARATOR . ini_get('include_path'));
```

para: (no meu caso o Cake está em `/usr/lib/Cake`)

```
ini_set('include_path', $ds . 'usr' . $ds . 'lib' . $ds . 'Cake' . $ds . 'lib' .PATH_SEPARATOR . ini_get('include_path'));
```

espero que ajude.